# Show Cities Related to Country Selected on Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, dictionary, ionic-framework

Using the repo here: https://github.com/country-regions/country-region-data/blob/master/data.js I am trying to map out the countries and cities related to that country.  I am unsure on how to approach this if anyone has any advice.

I want it so that if a user selects a country, the cities field only shows regions related to that country if that makes sense?

This is my code below currently, I use a map to map out the countries.  But I am unsure of how to map out the regions from the country selected?

```
<IonItem>
  <IonLabel position={"stacked"}>Country</IonLabel>
  <IonSelect interface="popover" value={values.country} name="country" placeholder="Select A Country" onIonChange={handleInputChange}>
      {countries.map((country) => (
          <IonSelectOption value={country.countryName} key={country.countryShortCode}>{country.countryName}</IonSelectOption>
      ))};
  </IonSelect>
</IonItem>
<IonItem>
  <IonLabel position={"stacked"}>City</IonLabel>
  <IonSelect interface="popover" value={values.city} name="city" placeholder="Select A City" onIonChange={handleInputChange}>
      {countries.map((country) => (
          <IonSelectOption value={country.countryName} key={country.countryShortCode}>{country.countryName}</IonSelectOption>
      ))};
  </IonSelect>
</IonItem>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend creating another state variable to have the regions of the selected country.
Then, in the function `handleInputChange`, you can assign the regions of the selected country to the variable.

Example:

```
function handleInputChange(e) {
    const { value, name } = e.currentTarget;

    if (name === 'country') {
       const selectedCounty = countries.find(county => country.countryName === value);
       setRegions(selectedCounty.regions);
    }

}
```

------------ Rest of the code --------------------

```
<IonItem>
  <IonLabel position={"stacked"}>Country</IonLabel>
  <IonSelect interface="popover" value={values.country} name="country" placeholder="Select A Country" onIonChange={handleInputChange}>
      {countries.map((country) => (
          <IonSelectOption value={country.countryName} key={country.countryShortCode}>{country.countryName}</IonSelectOption>
      ))};
  </IonSelect>
</IonItem>
<IonItem>
  <IonLabel position={"stacked"}>City</IonLabel>
  <IonSelect interface="popover" value={values.city} name="city" placeholder="Select A City" onIonChange={handleInputChange}>
      {regions.map((region) => (
          <IonSelectOption value={region.name} key={region.shortCode}>{region.name}</IonSelectOption>
      ))};
  </IonSelect>
</IonItem>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSX:

```
{countries.map((country) => (
          <IonSelectOption value={country.countryName} key={country.countryShortCode}>{country.countryName}</IonSelectOption>
      ))};
```

creates your options, so you just need to change `countries` to change those options.  To do that you could make a state variable:

```
const [citiesForCountries, setCitiesForCountries] = useState([]);
```

use it instead:

```
    {citiesForCountries.map((country) => ( // make options
```

Then, add an `onChange` handler to the first (ie. country) `IonSelect`, so that whenever it changes you update citiesForCountries:

```
const onChange = e => {
  const selectedCountry = countries.find(country => country.countryName === e.target.value);
  const newCitiesForCountries = selectectedCountry.cities;
  setCitiesForCountries(newCitiesForCountries);
}
```

NOTE: The above code assumes each country object has a "cities" property.  If it doesn't your change handler will need to find the `newCitiesForCountries` using your data instead.